# Reading 4 bytes from the end of a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, byte, reinterpret-cast

If I have a char* array:

```
char* c = getBytesFromSomewhere();
```

I'd like to read the last 4 bytes to a uint and then the previous 4 bytes etc. I tried this:

```
char* end = &c[size-5];
```

to get a pointer to the last 4 bytes in the array and then:

```
unsigned int n = *(reinterpret_cast<int *>(end));
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be an [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue?

Comment: what doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Also, you're subtracting a little too much.

Comment: Have you tried `memcpy`?

Comment: This also violates strict aliasing plus you have potential alignment problems. Use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets say the returned array is of size 8, it would look something like this in memory:

```
+---+
| c |
+---+
  |
  v
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

(The numbers inside is the indexes.)

Now if you make a new variable `e` to point at `c + size` it will point point to one beyond the end of the data:

```
+---+                           +---+
| c |                           | e |
+---+                           +---+
  |                               |
  v                               v
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you subtract `1` from `e` it now points to index `7`:

```
+---+                       +---+
| c |                       | e |
+---+                       +---+
  |                           |
  v                           v
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you subtract two (in total) `e` would point to index `6`, subtract `3` and `e` would be pointing at index `5` and subtract `4` and the index pointed to would be `4`. If you subtract `5` the pointer `e` would point to index `3`:

```
+---+       +---+
| c |       | e |
+---+       +---+
  |           |
  v           v
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And that's not four bytes from the end, that's *five* bytes from the end.

So you should be doing e.g.

```
char* end = c + size - 4;  /* Subtract by 4 and not 5 */
```

---

You should also be careful of the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), if the data comes from other systems e.g. over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

in the below code i do that :

```
char* end = (c + strlen(c) - 5);
unsigned int tst = 0;
tst = c[0];
tst = ((tst << 8) | c[1]);
tst = ((tst << 8) | c[2]);
tst = ((tst << 8) | c[3]);
```